# Hibernate несколько раз делает запросы

Tags: hibernate

Гибернейт при одном реквесте несколько раз вытягивает одну и туже сущность. В разных случаях по разному, один раз дважды, второй трижды. Кто может сказать с чем это связано ? И проблема ли это в принципе или возможно я не правильно понял работу гибернейта и на самом деле все правильно? Добавляю скрин, чтобы вы смогли увидеть запросы в базу в консоли. 
Так же если, это действительно повторное обращения к базе, скажите, что именно нужно добавить к вопросу (дао, сервисы, модели).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить 2 варианта:

1. Возможно, у вас неправильно объявлены связи между таблицами `Place` и `place_type`. Например, имеется 2 маппинга на таблицу *Place*: `PlaceFull` и `PlaceShort`. Оба имеют связь *many-to-one* на маппинг `PlaceType` таблицы *place_type*. В `PlaceType` имеется обратная связь, например, на `PlaceFull`. Если вы осуществите выборку из `PlaceShort`, то *Hibernate* после основной сущности осуществит выборку `PlaceType`. Увидев, что обратная связь из `PlaceType` ведёт не на уже выбранный `PlaceShort`, а на `PlaceFull`, *Hibernate* далее осуществит выборку из `PlaceFull`, а после неё опять из `PlaceType` (т.к. он замаплен и в `PlaceFull` тоже). Увидев, что последний выбранный `PlaceType` ссылается на уже выбранный `PlaceFull`, *Hibernate* на этом остановится. Таким образом получится последовательная выборка: `PlaceShort`->`PlaceType`->`PlaceFull`->`PlaceType`. Тот факт, что количество запросов меняется, может говорить о том, что некоторые записи в таблице *Place* могут не иметь ссылок на таблицу *place_type*, из-за чего *Hibernate* останавливается сразу.
2. Могут быть проблемы с многопоточностью. Тут вряд ли что-то можно подсказать - смотрите и отлаживайте самостоятельно. Если выложите проект, позволяющий воспроизвести проблему, возможно кто-то возьмётся за тестирование и поиск ошибки. Если процесс вызывается из некоего `CDI`-компонента уровня приложения, запускаемого при старте сервера, убедитесь в том, что обращения к БД делаются не из конструктора, а, например, из метода помеченного как `@PostConstruct`. Также, проблема может быть и при обращении извне к какому-либо компоненту сервера - сервер может создать и положить в пул компонентов сразу несколько экземпляров компонента ("про запас"), но на обработку запроса отдать только один из них. Если при этом компонент делает выборку из БД в конструкторе или в `@PostConstruct`, то обращение к БД будет выполнено независимо от того, было ли обращение к бизнес-методу компонента.

Если мои варианты не решают проблему, добавьте в вопрос исходные коды: как минимум маппинги и исходный код, осуществляющий чтение.